# I am having some serious troubles switching from SQLite to MYSQL with table creation queries

Tags: python, mysql-connector

```
sdb.cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS survivors (
        discord_id INT,
        username VARCHAR(255),
        `rank` ENUM('Legendary', 'Expert', 'Specialist', 'Seasoned', 'Skilled', 'Proficient', 'Settled', 'Known', 'New'),
        ll_activation DATE,
        pz_username VARCHAR(255),
        l4d2_username VARCHAR(255),
        pz_kills INT,
        l4d2_kills INT,
        admin_rank ENUM('SuperUser', 'Admin', 'Mod', 'ModMaker'),
        PRIMARY KEY (discord_id)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB
    ''')
```

This is my creation query - but I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bot/KYRBot.py", line 16, in on_ready
    db_manager.create_sdb_service()
  File "/home/bot/db_manager.py", line 91, in create_sdb_service
    sdb.cursor.execute('''
  File "/home/bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 342, in execute
    self._handle_result(result)
  File "/home/bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 236, in _handle_result
    self._handle_warnings()
  File "/home/bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 221, in _handle_warnings
    raise err
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1050: Table 'survivors' already exists
```

Why is MYSQL ignoring the `[IF NOT EXISTS]` Part of the statement?!

I apologise in advance for what is prob. a silly Q but I'm very new to development - I am going crazy with this :D !

I have read all the MYSQL documentation and don't see any reason why this doesn't work as intended... I have tried the statements directly into the MYSQL console and I get the same issue (orginally passed via mysql.connnector for python).

EDIT: I should add I've checked the MYSQL Version etc. and all this is fine. Is this suppose to throw an error in MYSQL as oppose to SQLite and I just need to handle gracefully?!

Comment: What is your mysql version? If you execute the query directly in a mysql client, then do you get an error or just a warning?

Comment: I have tried directly in MYSQL and I get the same error - it's actually crashing my Python App!

Thank you so much for the reply Sir / Ma'am.

Comment: I tried your query twice and I get a warning, not an error. I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour you described!

Comment: NO - sorry -it is working in MYSQL Console Directly now (syntax)...

How is the same query working in Console and not correctly in Python App?!

Comment: so :

    sdb.cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channels (
        id INT,
        name VARCHAR(255),
        type enum('text', 'voice'),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB
    ''')

Doesn't work... and 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channels (id INT,name VARCHAR(255),type enum('text', 'voice'),PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB

in console does work?!?!?!?

Comment: so the library I have in Python requires the error to be handled?!

Comment: My guess is that the python driver does not distinguish between warning and error

Comment: You are a HERO!!!!

'raise_on_warnings': True

....

Comment: THANK YOU SHADOWWWW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Please throw an answer up so I can +

Really appreciate you taking the time to reply to junior query.

Comment: You found the answer not me! Post a self answer providing the exact python driver you use and how you changed its setting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed It!

So using https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/ there is a standard variable set in the docs for the class constructor:

`'raise_on_warnings': True`

This will throw Errors for what are normally warnings such as a table already existing EVEN if you use `[IF NOT EXISTS]`

Either turn off the warnings permanently by setting to false:

`'raise_on_warnings': False`

Turn warnings off for that Specific Statement:

```
SET sql_notes = 0;      -- Temporarily disable the "Table already exists" warning
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...
SET sql_notes = 1;      -- And then re-enable the warning again
```

Or Handle the Error Gracefully!